# Нужно ли избавляться от менеджеров-классов при написании классов в UNITY 3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я сейчас пишу игры на `c#` в `UNITY`, и мне хотелось бы узнать, как лучше создавать классы.

Насколько я понимаю класс - это сущность из реального мира, перенесённая в код, у которой есть функции и тд.

Например, я создал класс `TimeManager`, в котором есть функции получения текущего множителя времени (от `0` до `1`) и функция, позволяющая задать множитель времени (тоже от `0` до `1`, используя `Mathf.clamp`).

Я использую этот класс для того, чтобы замедлять объекты в сцене. Грубо говоря я пилю клон `SUPERHOT`, где контролирую каждый объект и его `velocity`.

Мне бы хотелось узнать, как бы записали такой класс крутые программисты.

Если вопрос глупый, то не обессудьте, только на 2 курсе.

Comment: Система управления временем в Unity уже существует.

Answer (score 1):

Класс это не сущность от реального мира, а набор полей и методов, то есть информации и операций над ней. Классы могут быть абстрактными и совсем не реальными.

Какими должны быть классы и в принципе все, описано в пяти принципах `SOLID`. Начинать нужно с `Single Responsibility Principle`, `closed Principle` (`open` потом), и форматировать код согласно общепринятым конвенция языка.

Один из основных навыков, это навык нейминга (именования) классов, полей и методов, чему посвящают весомую долю страниц в книгах о программировании. Если класс называется `xxxManager` или `xxxController`, то ты сам не понимаешь чем он вообще занимается, но это что-то точно связано с `xxx`. `TimeManager` не чем явно не заведует и не управляет, а является статической точной доступа к множителю времени, то есть `TimeMultiplayer.value`.

Если бы ты тупо `Ok Google: Unity3d game speed`, сразу бы узнал, что такой класс в `Unity3D` уже есть и меняет скорость игры `Time.timeScale`. Только не говори, что `Google` проходят на 3ем курсе.

Comment: Я знаю, что есть Time.timescale, но мне нужно было, чтобы камера могла двигаться без замедления. Насколько я помню, этот метод замедляет абсолютно всё.

Comment: [Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html).[unscaledDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html)

Comment: @Baerere - Yaroslav, тагай собеседника в комментах, иначе он не получит нотификашку о сообщении. Без тагания нотификашку получает автоматом только автор поста, под которым коммент.

Comment: @Yaroslav Долго не мог ответить, апгрейдил компьютер. Я не совсем понимаю, как я должен использовать этот параметр. Можно пример?